# Anyone write a Requests BaseAdapter that supports HTTP/3?

Tags: python, python-requests, baseadapter, http3

I like Python Requests but have run into a slight issue. I need to extend it to support HTTP/3 (i.e. HTTP using UDP with the QUIC protocol, instead of TCP). I was wondering if anyone knows of a BaseAdapter to support HTTP/3 or knows where there is one. I thought I would ask first before spending the time to implement one.

Thanks.

I tried writing a HTTP/3 Adapter, but Requests depends on URLLIB3 to do all the messaging, and it doesn't support HTTP/3 either.

Comment: Based on what you write you don't need an adapter for generic UDP, but specific for HTTP/3. I've changed your question accordingly.